# Is every point contained in a proper open set of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $a\in X$. Is it always true that $a$ is contained in a proper open set of $X$? I don't know how to derive it directly by the axioms of a topological space.

Comment: By definition of a topology on $X$, $X$ is open. Since $a \in X$, the answer is yes.

Comment: The axioms say that $X$ is itself one of the open sets,

Comment: Oh thanks! I see. But how if we require the open sets to be proper? (I edit the question now.)

Comment: No but a lot of the topological spaces people think about have this property. For instance, in terms of the separation axioms, $T_1$ implies this.

Comment: Also note that the set of $a\in X$ that do have a proper open neighborhood is an open subspace $U\subset X$, and this subspace completely determines the topology for $X$.

Comment: Given non-empty $X$ and $a\in X$, $X$ itself, together with all sets that do not contain $a$ defines a topology on $X$.

Comment: You mean proper **subset**; the term "proper set" does not exist as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

No. Indeed, the "trivial topology" in which only the empty set and the full space are open, is a valid topology. It's not very interesting, but it does satisfy the axioms.

Comment: I have heard it as the indiscreet topology, to contrast with the discrete topology, but the idea is the same.

Comment: The trivial topology on a one-point set is a perfectly respectable space: compact Hausdorff,  metrizable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, this need not be the case: if $X$ is a set and $p \in X$ then the following defines a topology on $X$ (th excluded point topology w.r.t. $p$):

$$\mathcal{T}= \{A \subseteq X: p \notin A\} \cup \{X\}$$

It's easy to check this satisfies the axioms of a topology. And it's also clear that the only open set that contains $p$ is $X$ itself.

But very often additional assumptions on $X$ exist, e.g. $T_1$ (for every pair $x \neq y$ of points in $X$ there is an open set $O$ such that $x \in O$, and $y \notin O$. This guarantees that there are enough open sets so that every point is contained in a proper open set. The above example is merely $T_0$, not $T_1$. Where $T_0$ means that for every $x \neq y$ we have an open set $O$ such that ($x \in O$ and $y \notin O$) *or* ($x \notin O$ and $y \in O$), which does hold as one of the $x$ or $y$ is unequal to $p$ (say $x$) and we then use $O=\{x\}$. So $T_0$ does not guarantee this property, and the stronger $T_1$ does. So if you desire such a property for a space $X$, assume such "separation axioms" on it.

Comment: Sierpinski space (exactly 2 points, exactly 3 open sets) is  the smallest example of a $T_0$ space without "this property".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Sierpiński space is exactly the excluded point topology on a 2 point set so a counterexample as I said. $T_0$ and not $T_1$. I said $T_1$-ness guarantees the desired property.